# Break out of a function from keyboard

Tags: javascript, keyboard

The annoying thing is, I had this working. I cut out the code to tidy up ... but forgot to save the pasted section  in text editor !!

The premise is this: People type a message into a textarea. They then click a button, which calls a function, and opens a div that displays that modified message. But ... I now want them to click the keyboard for the  to get hidden again, (ie the keyboard triggers another function)

I can't use a listener / addEvent in the body tag since they are also entering detail for textarea. Don't think it would be any good in the function as that returns as soon as it's modified the text. I =THINK= I need a loop at the latter end of function so that it keeps repolling the addEvent or similar.

Or other suggestions?

Comment: Should the div be visible during the textarea keyboard input?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are asking for. If the user starts typing agin it will hide the preview div. However, it might just be better to have an 'active' preview that evolves as they type.

```js
const previewDiv = () => document.querySelector('#preview');
const textArea = () => document.querySelector('input[type="textarea"]');
const preview = () => document.querySelector('button');

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  textArea().addEventListener('keydown', () => previewDiv().setAttribute('class', 'hide'));
  preview().addEventListener('click', () => {
    console.log('test');
    previewDiv().setAttribute('class', 'show');
    console.log(previewDiv());    
    previewDiv().innerHTML = textArea().value;
  });
});
```

```css
#preview {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
}

.show {
  display: block;
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<input type="textarea" />
<button>Preview</button>
<div id="preview" class="hide"></div>
```

This is a live type version of above, as the user types, we can preview output.

```js
const previewDiv = () => document.querySelector('#preview');
const textArea = () => document.querySelector('input[type="textarea"]');


document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  textArea().addEventListener('keyup', () => {
    previewDiv().innerHTML = textArea().value;
  });
});
```

```css
#preview {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<input type="textarea" />

<div id="preview"></div>
```

Comment: I've been doing some experimenting, and came up with this little code to show what I mean. The clock in first box is just to give the script something to do, (this would actually being a div that covers whole screen and scrolls text) If you press the space bar, it exits timer (scroll) and returns to screen, and you can enter text in second box without space bar affecting text entry. But interestingly, when you hit START button to start process again ... it doesn't, complaining of a missing identifier at line 1 (?)

Comment: <input type="submit" onclick="Start Timer();" text="START">
<textarea id="demo"></textarea>
<textarea id="text"></textarea>

<script>
var myVar = setInterval(myTimer, 1000);
document.addEventListener('keydown', checkKey, true);
myTimer();
function StartTimer(){
var myVar = setInterval(myTimer, 1000);
document.addEventListener('keydown', checkKey, true);
myTimer();
//return false;
}
function myTimer() {
  var d = new Date();
  var t = d.toLocaleTimeString();
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = t; 
}
 Part 1 of 2

Comment: function checkKey(evt) {
  if (evt.keyCode === 32) {
 clearInterval(myVar);
document.removeEventListener('keydown', checkKey, false);
alert('We have broken free');
}
}
</script>

Comment: WOULDN'T YA KNOW ... Earlier, this seemed to work. Now I've posted, it doesn't !

Comment: Sorry folks! The error is in the submit button ... trying to call "Start Timer()" and not "StartTimer" Schoolboy error or what? (Only taken me an hour to find it !!)

Comment: Assume you are all sorted now ?